# Asp.net mvc password check: Weak, Normal, Strong

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanna make a password check for the webshop that im building for school. Thats indicated with color alert: so red for weak, orange, for normal, and green foor good.
What could be the best approach to do this?

Here is a little section of where the user need to put in a password:

```
        password
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Klant.password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Klant.password)
    </div>
```

This is a homework assignment, and we are informed we're not allowed to use javascript.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20PasswordStrength%20Control.ashx

Comment: Welcome to SO. We expect you to show research effort. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would definitely be to do this on the client using javascript. I wrote a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) function for you which does the following:

1. Executes every time a key press occurs in your password text box
2. Evaluates the text length
3. Changes the background colour of a div based on password length

**Note:** Simply download jQuery(if you don't have it already in the Scripts folder) and add a reference to it in your view and make sure the id of the password text box is correct(I've called mine "Password")

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //"Password" is the id of the password textbox
        //yours may be different so make sure to change this if necessary
        $("#Password").keyup(function () {
            var length = $("#Password").val().length;
            var colour = "";

            if (length <= 4)
                colour = "red";
            else if (length <= 7)
                colour = "orange";
            else
                colour = "green";

            $("#strength").css("background-color", colour);
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        <div id="strength" style="width:100px;height:20px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

If you don't come right I've created a sample project and uploaded it to [Google drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iPiW5jXDdPd3BFbVJTamhkbWs/edit?usp=sharing).Just click File->Download to get the .zip file

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript code for checking strength:

```
function pwdStrength(password)
{
        var desc = new Array();
        desc[0] = "Very Weak";
        desc[1] = "Weak";
        desc[2] = "Better";
        desc[3] = "Medium";
        desc[4] = "Strong";
        desc[5] = "Strongest";
        var score   = 0;
        //if password bigger than 6 give 1 point
        if (password.length > 6) score++;
        //if password has both lower and uppercase characters give 1 point      
        if ( ( password.match(/[a-z]/) ) && ( password.match(/[A-Z]/) ) ) score++;
        //if password has at least one number give 1 point
        if (password.match(/\d+/)) score++;
        //if password has at least one special caracther give 1 point
        if ( password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/) ) score++;
        //if password bigger than 12 give another 1 point
        if (password.length > 12) score++;
         document.getElementById("pwdDescription").innerHTML = desc[score];
         document.getElementById("pwdStrength").className = "strength" + score;
}
```

Apart from this you can refer following links:

http://passwordadvisor.com/CodeAspNet.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f9935e/password-policystrength-Asp-Net-mvc-validator/

Comment: I am doubtfull about its usage with above lines of code now. But you can try with javascript as link i have suggested.

Comment: I didnt work,or i did something wrong.. i think i need to approach this differently..:(

Comment: If you just copy and paste pieces of code from somewhere, you should at least name the source and tell what the code does. FYI: this code is crap and should not be used.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have written appropriate links which can help user. And if you know the answer kindly post it and help the user.

Comment: There is no "the answer". I'm just saying the code in your answer doesn't help, also a little explanation for the links you posted would also be welcome.

Comment: obviously its not working, its written in above comments by operator and also if it would have worked, he would have been accepted my answer, still its not. This is enough to show this code is not working.